# Can't find classes annotated with ConditionalOnWebApplication using spring reflection

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations

In our WebApplication class I want to find all the classes that annotated with `@Configuration`.
I'm using the below code to do it:

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Configuration.class));

Set<BeanDefinition> configurationBeans = scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.company");
```

But `findCandidateComponents` is not returnnig the classes that annotated with both `@Configuration` and `@ConditionalOnWebApplication` .

I change the filter to the below, just to test:

```
scanner.addIncludeFilter(new `AnnotationTypeFilter(ConditionalOnWebApplication.class));`
```

and I got no classes.

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider uses a org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator which might exclude the missing classes, cause @ConditionalOnWebApplication is not fulfilled.

Set a breakpoint at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider#isConditionMatch to see what the conditionEvaluator is doing there.

From your question I cannot see, what you want to use this for. If you want to see, which @Configuration annotated classes are in the running spring context, you might better use [ListableBeanfactory.getBeansWithAnnotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29)

This gives you exactly the annotated beans of the running app, whereas your current approach makes its own class path scan, which may lead to different results.